# Disabling caching in crosswalk

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, crosswalk-runtime

I'm using ionic with crosswalk.
I know that app with crosswalk is much bigger that without it.
But I see that crosswalk is caching data (guess images and data from internet) and app is even bigger when navigating.
Can I disable it??

Answer (score 1):

Yes! That is a big problem.

You can call:`XWalkView.clearCache()` in onCreate or onDestroy method.

Also the constant `RELOAD_IGNORE_CACHE` would ignore cache files on startup. But I have not used it till now.

Comment: But how to use it? where? in JS?

Comment: @piernik no, that would be in your Main Activity file (Java) if I'm not mistaken. No clue about ionic though.

Answer (score 0):

How about to add  --disk-cache-size = 0 ?

https://crosswalk-project.org/jira/browse/XWALK-3821

Comment: As I said I'm using ionic and not istalling it with commend line :/